how do I draw text on image
I found that Halcon only defines disp_text, but this function only displays the text in a window.
I know we can use GDI+ or other gaphics API,such as opengl, but it's not "nature".
I wonder if I'm missing some details, thank you!

dump_window_image? if that works for you, let me know so I can post it as an answer and you can accept the answer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using
Row:=10
Column:=10
Text:='Some Text'
dev_get_window(CurrentWindowHandle)
set_tposition(CurrentWindowHandle, Row, Column)
write_string(CurrentWindowHandle, Text)
dump_window_image(image, CurrentWindowHandle)

As pointed out by Christoph Rackwitz, dump_window_image works for that. its not a straight forward solution, but it does its job. Thanks to Chris at this point, because i was just looking for that answer.
